# How to start to use "using NativeWifi" while creating Desktop Windows App

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio, winapp

I cannnot find how to add "using NativeWifi" for Windows 7 Desktop App (Windows Form or WPF App) in the project of Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional. There is the description https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556(v=vs.85).aspx but I miss the basic guide how to start to implement it. I get the error of missing references or assemblies but there is no that kind of reference among the possible references of the project. So, how practically to use it or it was removed from the new versions of Microsoft Visual Studio, then where I can download it?

Comment: Check out Managed wifi api https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Interop.cs if you're trying to work with the wifi, it's easier to use

Comment: How is it possible to do it without Managed WiFi API?

Comment: codeplex is down, enter in https://github.com/ and search for "nativewifi" repositories.